# Script to invite all team members to a new Slack channel

Tags: javascript, console, slack

I am trying to add every member of a slack to a new channel I'm creating. (Because there are 7k+ member, this is not something I want to do by hand every time it comes up.) There are many OLD examples of how to do this out there, but they are all outdated due to slack no longer including jQuery in their database as well as some class and id changes. I'm very close to getting the code working, but missing one key step, so looking for help in resolving.

I started by working off the last solution provided in this very old post: https://gist.github.com/YitzhakAndrade/1c7c2f7ac98520c9c84d536880f96770

Original (but very old code) code here (Note: Instructions would be to browse to the appropriate slack channel in a browser and paste the script into your Chrome/Firefox dev console and hit enter.):

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
async function inviteAllUsers() {      
   for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
      await sleep(300);
    $('#channel_actions_toggle').click();
      await sleep(300);
    $('#channel_invite_item').click();
      await sleep(300);
     for(var k = 0; k < letters.length; k++){
        var word = letters[i] + letters[k];
        await sleep(300);
        $("#channel_invite_filter").val(word).trigger("input");
        $(".channel_invite_member:not(hidden)").each(function(i, obj) {
            foundAny=true;
            this.click();
        });
      }
      await sleep(300);
      $('.invite_go').click()
    }
}

inviteAllUsers(); 
setInterval(inviteAllUsers,600*1000);
```

As mentioned above, jQuery is no longer included in the slack database among other things so that code no longer works.

This is my current version of the re-write with issues detailed inline:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

var simulateClick = function(elem) {
  // Create our event (with options)
  var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
  });
  // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
  var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};

// var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var letters = "ab";
async function inviteAllUsers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    await sleep(300);
    // Opens up the settings menu
    simulateClick(document.querySelector(".c-icon--cog-o"));
    await sleep(300);
    // Selects the "Add People to Channel" selection
    simulateClick(
      document.querySelectorAll(".c-menu__items .c-menu_item__li button")[1]
    );
    await sleep(300);
    for (var k = 0; k < letters.length; k++) {
      var word = letters[i] + letters[k];
      console.log(word);
      await sleep(300);
      // Inputs current word into the search field
      simulateClick(document.querySelector(".c-multi-select input"));
      document.querySelector(".c-multi-select input").value = word;
      // document.querySelector(".c-multi-select input").value = 'a';
      document
        .querySelector("#channel_invite_modal_select")
        .setAttribute("value", word);
      // document.querySelector("#channel_invite_modal_select").setAttribute('value', 'a');

      // THIS IS WHERE MY ISSUE LIES
      // By just adjusting the value in this way, I'm unable to actually have slack retrieve the matching filtered slack names.
      // When interacting with slack normally, the filtered list is shown upon typing in a letter.
      // With the script, although the letter will populate and the value will change to what's passed in,
      // it's as though something just isn't being triggered.

      // Once I get it so that the options will populate, I'll want to add the list provided.

      // I'm thinking something like below should work:
      document
        .querySelectorAll(".c-select_options_list__option")
        .forEach(function(option) {
          simulateClick(option)
        });
    }

    // Then, once all the names are selected, click the "Add" button.
    simulateClick(
      document.querySelectorAll(
        ".c-button[data-qa='invite_to_workspace_submit_button']"
      )
    );

    await sleep(300);
  }
}

inviteAllUsers();
setInterval(inviteAllUsers, 600 * 1000);
```

As you can see inline with the code, although I  am able to get to the appropriate modal and have managed to change the input value in the search field, I'm currently unable to actually have slack retrieve the matching filtered slack names. I assume I'm just missing the triggering of something, but I don't know what.

Would love any help in determining what step I'm missing in order to access the list of options and get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @SeanKilleen, I actually had to do this recently and decided to try his approach to copy 1530 users from one channel to another.

I have documented my approach and script used at the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/norganna/12686901c0d802ed112d911ee24bc68c

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the brevity -- not currently feeling too hot -- but I think I might be able to point you in the right direction.

There's a slack API client for JS here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@slack/web-api and I believe a reference on the site. It appears to be well supported / maintained.

I think you'd then get all users using `users.list`: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list

And then add them to a channel using `channel.invite`: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.invite

By using those features (and probably some pagination loops on the getting all users part), I think that'd do it for you.

(Edit: I realize that this offers something that may not actually for your approach and that assumes you'd be willing to adapt to it. If you're interested in this route, I'd be happy to try to support it. Feel free to DM @sjkilleen on Twitter.)